# How can I resolve the USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS error when using Docusign Connector in Workato?

Tags: docusignapi, workato

I am using the Docusign Connector in Workato and want to be able to use the action `Send document using a template` as part of my recipe. When I add that action though, I get an error:

```
Something went wrong
{ "errorCode": "USER_LACKS_PERMISSIONS", "message": "This user lacks sufficient permissions to access this resource." }
```

See the error in Workato here:

[image]

I searched the docusign website and found this article that looked promising: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/DocuSign-Developer-FAQs-General-Administration-and-Authentication#User-Lacks-Permission-Error

The article says to enable the **Allow sender to download form data** setting which I have done but it has made no difference.

I believe the error is occuring because the Workato Connector is trying to download a list of the templates available and it is that REST call that is failing. Are there any other settings that would affect this that I should change in my admin config? Does anyone know why this issue might be occuring?

My Docusign account is an admin account and I can see all of the templates in our organisation when viewing via the Docusign web portal.

Thanks for any assistance that can be provided

Comment: it could be that you are using two different accounts, or using different env/servers.
How do you authenticate to Workato? I'm not familiar with this connector so not sure how it works exactly.

Comment: Workato uses OAuth to connect to my account in Docusign. So when setting up the connection, I have to log in to Docusign as part of the connection process to establish permissions.

Comment: do you go to account.docusign.com or account-d.docusign.com ?

Comment: I have both a login to the production and the developer instances of Docusign. The Workato connector abstracts that from the end user though and provides a toggle for whether it is a production account or a demo/developer account. When I select developer, it all connects fine and the error does not appear. When it is on production, the error appears.

Comment: that is the reason. Let me write a formal answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I have taken for this was to create a new user specifically for the integration I was trying to set up. The new user is **NOT** a DS-Admin user and was only granted **USE** template permissions in the user permissions. This user works with the integration and is what I will proceed with.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** make sure the production user has the full permission to read templates, you claim this is an administrator user, can you confirm this?

You cannot mix up production and demo (developer) account information.
If you use a user from one environment, even if the email and password and name and all is the same - it's completely different in DocuSign.
The one cannot access the other.
You will need to have everything moved to your production account if you want to use this. Meaning the template has to be moved to your production account and the correct templateID from production (not the same!) would be used.

Comment: Thanks,what you have said is correct, but that is not my issue. I am not trying to use the same template ID across environments. I initially only had a production environment and this error occurred. After trying to resolve it I created a developer account to see if the error would still occur there or not. It doesn't, which suggests the connector is ok in itself. Note that the error occurs when the connector is trying to read the list of templates from the account. We have not got to the stage yet of sending anything as we can't even read the templates and select the one that we want.

Comment: well, it's also possible your user in production is not an admin like you think and cannot read the list of templates.

Comment: When I log into the docusign portal, I can see all the templates. I have also checked the groups and my user is a DS Admin.

Comment: a DS admin for the account with the templates will not get the above error. I believe that you are not using the same account when you go the DocuSign portal that you use from Workato. I cannot confirm this, but this is the only valid explanation. You may need to call Workato customer support or DocuSign customer support to get all the details.

Comment: Thanks @inbar-gazit, you got me thinking further and I created a new user specifically for the interation that I am trying to create. So instead of using my own user account in Docusign with DS-Admin rights, I now use a different login that has a custom permisison group created for it, with less permission access than the DS-Admin (such as no admin rights and use templates user permission). This user works from within Workato and is a good working solution. Still no idea why my account would not work, but that does not matter now I have this account working.

Comment: maybe your DS-Admin group is not set to see templates, that would be weird and unusual. Admins typically are the superuser that has every possible permission. Your account may be set differently for some reason.